# Pvalues of coefficients in Lasso in scikit-learn

Tags: python, r, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I ran an L1 regularization on 19 features with 143 observations. While Lasso did give me coefficients with zero value thereby helping in further reduce features (I had initially done a preliminary feature reduction by running a combination of random forests and LARS).

But the problem is while it does tell me coefficient estimates and I can get a regression equation, if I have to explain the feature importance to someone, they would want to see how much confidence there is on those coefficients. Without showing any p-value of coefficient, people are sceptical.

So is there a way to get p-value for Lasso coefficients from scikit learn? Or in R? I guess even R does not give that.

Comment: You will have better luck with this question on http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also p-value or significance with respect to lasso is a new thing http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/papers/lassosignif.pdf.

Comment: How about bootstrapping and getting the frequency at which each variable is included in LASSO-ed model?

Comment: Don't perpetuate the problems with using p-values to determine importance. The coefficients are estimates of effect size. If you standardise your features so they're all on the same scale, coefficients can be compared to one another for "importance". For uncertainty in effect, use bootstrapping to produce intervals for the coefficients.